# How to redefine font family for different sizes (\huge, \large, etc.)

Tags: fonts, lmodern

**How can I change the font family just for certain font sizes?**

My document is using sans-serif fonts via `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`, but I would like to have serifs on `\huge` and `\LARGE`.

In the following MWE I get the results I want, because lmodern does not have small caps for `\huge` (20.74 pt) and `\LARGE` (17.28 pt).

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \huge \textsc{Some Title Words}
    
    \LARGE \textsc{Some Other Title Words}
\end{document}
```

But this can hardly be a solution, because the following errors are produced:

> Font shape 'T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <20.74> not available(Font) Font shape 'T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead
>
> Font shape 'T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <17.28> not available(Font) Font shape 'T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead

Comment: can't you just use `\LARGE\textrm{something}` to locally get out of sans-serif?

Comment: `\huge\textrm{Some Title Words}` if I understood you correctly… (http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/27)

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, especially because I do only have about 3 lines of `\huge` and `\LARGE` in my document. However, how would this be achieved, if I had used it a lot and would not want to write `\textrm{}` every time?

Comment: @basseur if you had this a lot it would probably have a semantic meaning (for example a heading) in which case you'd define a semantic macro (cf. `\section`) where the definition would contain all font setup for the element